# D3D11: E_OUTOFMEMORY when mapping vertex buffer

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, directx

In my Unity game, I have to modify a lot of graphic resources like textures and vertex buffers via native code to keep good performance.

The problems start when code calls ID3D11ImmediateContext::Map several times in a very short time (I mean very short - called from different threads running parallel). There is no rule if mapping is successful or not. Method call looks like

```
ID3D11DeviceContext* sU_m_D_context;


void* BeginModifyingVBO(void* bufferHandle)
{
    ID3D11Buffer* d3dbuf = static_cast<ID3D11Buffer*>(bufferHandle);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
    HRESULT res = sU_m_D_context->Map(d3dbuf, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mapped);

    assert(mapped.pData);

    return mapped.pData;
}


void FinishModifyingVBO(void* bufferHandle)
{
    ID3D11Buffer* d3dbuf = static_cast<ID3D11Buffer*>(bufferHandle);

    sU_m_D_context->Unmap(d3dbuf, 0);
}



std::mutex sU_m_D_locker;

void Mesh::ApplyBuffer()
{
    sU_m_D_locker.lock();

    // map buffer
    VBVertex* mappedBuffer = (VBVertex*)BeginModifyingVBO(this->currentBufferPtr);

    memcpy(mappedBuffer, this->mainBuffer, this->mainBufferLength * sizeof(VBVertex));

    // unmap buffer
    FinishModifyingVBO(this->currentBufferPtr);

    sU_m_D_locker.unlock();

    this->markedAsChanged = false;
}
```

where d3dbuf is dynamic vertex buffer. I don't know why, but sometimes result is E_OUTOFMEMORY, despite there is a lot of free memory. I tried to surround code with mutexes - no effect.

Is this really memory problem or maybe something less obvious?

Comment: memcpy is not normally threadsafe. Where have you put your mutexes of critical sections?

Comment: Even if all of sample code is locked with 1 mutex, the problem still exists.

Comment: Then present your [MCVE]

Comment: Updated in first post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the device context methods are thread safe. If you are going to use them from several threads you will need to either manually sync *all* the calls, or use multiple (deferred) contexts, one per thread. See [Introduction to Multithreading in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also error checking should be better: you need to always check returned `HRESULT` values because in case of failure something like `assert(mapped.pData);` may still succeed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately I'm not able to create deferred contexts (probably Unity is creating d3d11 device with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED flag or I'm doing something wrong). I'll try to synchronize the calls with engine's calls, what can be difficult to do without source code access :/

Comment: Thanks! Synchronizing all the calls has solved my problem. I wonder why method returned E_OUTOFMEMORY instead of something more corresponding to real error. D3D11 is lier :P

Comment: @MrDyrektor By executing not thread safe method concurrently your application was facing an Undefined Behavior. So the results you were getting were random. Enabling debug mode while creating DXGI factory and DirectX device may detect and report some concurrency-related problems.